# In vim, is there a way to map the umlaut letters to the normal ones for jumping?

Tags: vim

The result I wish for:

When I type `f a`, the cursor jumps to the next `a` or `ä`, so basically an `ä` is mapped to an `a` (but only for the purpose of jumping).

This could be applied to many cases, for example to match a Chinese period `。` by typing `.`. So you can match and jump to those characters you can only type with another keyboard layout.

Is there a way to do this kind of mapping?

Comment: It seems this feature is implemented in the [vim-sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak) plugin using equivalence classes, see this [comment](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak/issues/173#issuecomment-223659821). Can you try it?